# Flutter Location distance valid values but returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, location

I'm using the GeoFlutterFire package, I'm getting the current locaion using the location package,
the right values are being assigned to the distnance method it prints the distance in the console and immediately after prints error

```
The method 'distance' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: distance(lat: 32.093135, lng: 34.8667283)
```

You can see the values assigned to the method are valid and I couldn't figure out why null is being returned

The Code:

```
class HandlyCallTile extends StatefulWidget {
final HandlyCall handlyCall;

HandlyCallTile({this.handlyCall});

@override
_HandlyCallTileState createState() => _HandlyCallTileState();
}

class _HandlyCallTileState extends State<HandlyCallTile> {
String _rwrd;

final String mapsUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=';

double lat, lng, dist;

LocationData locationData;
GeoFirePoint myLocation;
final geo = GeoFlutterFire();

current() async {
locationData = await getLocation();
myLocation = geo.point(latitude: locationData.latitude, longitude: locationData.longitude);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

setState(() {
  lat = widget.handlyCall.location.latitude;
  lng = widget.handlyCall.location.longitude;
  dist = myLocation.distance(lat: lat, lng: lng);
});

print(dist);
```

the getLocation function:

```
Future getLocation () async {


Location location = new Location();
bool _serviceEnabled;
PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
LocationData _locationData;


_serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
_serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
if (!_serviceEnabled) {
  return;
}
}


_permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
_permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
  return;
}
}

_locationData = await location.getLocation();

return _locationData;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are calling 'distance' on 'myLocation', but 'myLocation' wasn't initialized.

You are assigning values to 'myLocation' inside your 'current()' function. But I don't see that you are calling this function anywhere in the code, but you are only defining it. You can either call it directly when you need to use, or you can put it inside initState

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    current();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then, move your setState logic inside the current function, because it appears that you want it to  run directly when the widget loads, your dart file should look like this in the end:

```
String distance = 'Distance is...';

current() async {
locationData = await getLocation();
myLocation = geo.point(latitude: locationData.latitude, longitude: locationData.longitude);

lat = widget.handlyCall.location.latitude;
lng = widget.handlyCall.location.longitude;
dist = myLocation.distance(lat: lat, lng: lng);

setState(() {
distance = distance + dist.toString();
   });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    current();
    super.initState();
  }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: Center(
child:Text(distance));
}
```

This will display a text widget saying 'Distance is..' when the screen opens, and as soon as the location is done calculating the distance, it'll display for example 'Distance is 500'.

Comment: First of all thank you, though now it returns 0,
Maybe I need to do active location tracking? to know the distance between the use and the point

Comment: You're welcome, if it's returning zero, then it's calculating a distance, and most likely you are subtracting the same geopoint. i.e mylocation is the same as the coordinates passed down to the widget.

If there was an error, you'd see it.

Change the coordinates being passed down to your widget, or hardCode them to test it.
If this answer has resolved your bug\error, please mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hard coding the location get me the result but using the methods does not...

Comment: What location did you hard code? You should hardcode `widget.handlyCall.location.latitude` & `widget.handlyCall.location.longitude` and keep `myLocation` dynamic, to make sure that geolocator is working. Please update on the results of this.

Comment: eventually live location solved my problem, but thank you for your help so much!!

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I want with live location calculations and it solved my problem, I guess because I'm using ListView.builder to create the list it needs constant updats for the location cause with the solution of @Huthaifa Muayyad above it solved the problem partially and only some of the tiles got distance values and the others null.

[I've use this great video to implement the live location solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hbONxgWhLo&t=567)

and this is my code now, much simpler and working:

```
final geo = GeoFlutterFire();
var locationModel = Provider.of<LocationModel>(context);
var point = geo.point(latitude: handlyCall.location.latitude, longitude: 
handlyCall.location.longitude);

var distance = point.distance(lat: locationModel.latitude, lng: 
locationModel.longitude);
```

The list builder inside of the statless widget:

```
return StreamProvider<LocationModel>(
  create: (_) => LocationService().getStreamData,
  child: ListView.builder(
    cacheExtent: 100.0,
    itemCount: handlyCalls.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return HandlyCallTile(handlyCall: handlyCalls[index],);
      }
  ),
);
```

the LocationModel model:

```
class LocationModel {
final double latitude;
final double longitude;

const LocationModel({@required this.latitude, @required this.longitude});
}
```

and the LocationService:

```
class LocationService{

Location location = new Location();
LocationModel currentLocation;

StreamController<LocationModel> locationController = 
StreamController<LocationModel>.broadcast();

Stream<LocationModel> get getStreamData => locationController.stream;


LocationService() {
location.requestPermission().then((locationPermission) {
  if (locationPermission == PermissionStatus.granted){
    location.onLocationChanged.listen((locationValue) {
      locationController.add(
        LocationModel(latitude: locationValue.latitude, longitude: 
locationValue.longitude)
       );
     });
   }
 });
 }

}
```